# NI Measurement Studio alternative

Tags: mfc, measurement, measurement-studio

I need an alternative to NI Measurement Studio for MFC/C++ applications, since they don't support them anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The Measurement Studio C++ MFC libraries are now considered legacy but National Instruments is still providing these libraries with support for Visual Studio 2010 (and soon for Visual Studio 2012) to customers who are current on their Standard Service Program (SSP) or have purchased the most recent version of Measurement Studio.

The Legacy Support policy for Measurement Studio can be found here: http://www.ni.com/mstudio/legacysupport/

You can even still receive support for versions of Visual Studio older than 2010.